# Log every IP connecting on a system with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, logging, filter, accounting

Title says it all.

How can I, with iptables under Linux, log all IP connecting to a server?
As a little detail, I'd like to have only ONE entry in the log PER DAY PER IP.

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

I narrowed it down to 5 packets logged for every new session which is weird since I use *--hashlimit 1 --haslimit-burst 1*, I suspect that --m limit which defaults to 5 plays a role in there. Trouble is, if I set --m limit to 1, only 1 entry is logged for ALL IP instead one per EACH IP.

The reason I want to do this is also to avoid as much as possible logs growing too fast since this will be a rather unmanaged box.

**EDIT2:**
Here is my current try, in a iptables-restore format:
(on several lines for ease of reading)

```
-A FORWARD -d 10.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW 
-m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/min --hashlimit-burst 1 
--hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name denied-client 
-j LOG --log-prefix "iptables (denied client): "
```

Comment: What service?  http, mysql, other?

Comment: https for example, although the part about service I can handle, it is the logging part that is giving me trouble ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try this:

```
# IP address entry older than one day
iptables -A ... -m recent --name mydaily ! --rcheck ! --seconds 86400 -j logandset
# IP address never seen before
iptables -A ... -m recent --name mydaily ! --rcheck -j logandset

# Custom chain for logging and refreshing
iptables -N logandset
iptables -A logandset -j LOG
iptables -A logandset -m recent --name mydaily --set
```

So your list `mydaily` will keep track of the last seen IP addresses, and if it was never seen before, or if the last seen is older than one day, the packet will be logged, and the list entry for that IP address be updated.

You should probably set `ip_list_tot` to a higher value for `mydaily`, as explained in the iptables manpage (In your case for /proc/net/xt_recent/mydaily).

Comment: Both lines have to be  "! --rcheck" to work but that's it!
Thanks a bunch! Good bounty hunt ;)

Comment: Thanks! I corrected it to `! --rcheck`.

Comment: Actually works with just the first line:
"! --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j logandset"

Comment: (And you forgot to remove the second ! from the first line)

Comment: Are you sure? My current version seems to work for me (maybe I haven't tested it enough). I'll give it a spin on my server - because logging IPs just once per day is a good idea anyway! Then I'll edit my answer. Hm, maybe both versions work? Iptables' `recent` module has a bit of a strange syntax IMO: Actually it should check, that that the address is in the list (--rcheck), but that its timestamp is older than 86400 (! --seconds). But maybe the arguments must be read as a bracket term.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild (untested) crack @ this, but something like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix 'IPT/New Connection'
```

iptables will emit a message to the kernel log for every new connection.  You will then need to do something like

```
grep 'IPT/New Connection' /var/log/kern.log | | wc -l
```

Which will give you a count.  Various dances w/ awk/perl/etc will let you split it up by IP.

I don't see a way to convince IPtables to spit out just one count per IP address at the end of the day.  If your syslog is capable of filteirng messages by regexp, you can capture the messages and funnel them into a seperate log file.  @ the end of the day, all the counts are computed, and the message is reinserted into your main syslog entry.

Comment: prefixing and extracting are not the main focus here, but the one entry/day/ip is. Let me show you what I got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be much simpler to just log everything and then post process it to extract what you need? Use what's appropriate at each stage rather than try to shoehorn something to fit where it doesn't belong.

Comment: That's usually what I try to do but I am asked to keep this log to bare minimum, so I figured I'd ask just in case someone has a better iptables logging knowledge than I do. I will post my lines soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a patched version of [ulogd](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/index.html) with an SQL backend.

The trick would be to patch the **INSERT** SQL query in a way that would let the database deal with redundancy in IP addresses and insert new records into the logs only for unique IPs.

Comment: I'd rather stay on a plain text version than have to install a db server just for that. On a system where SQL is already installed, sure is a good way.

Comment: You could use sqlite, which is trivial to install, requires 0 configuration and is supported by ulogd as backend. It can also store its databases in RAM, so this might suit you as well, especially on servers with big uptime.